# How to calculate torch.mean with default value for empty slice?

Tags: python, pytorch

What's the correct way to calculate `torch.mean` such that in case of an empty slice, some default value would be returned?

```
import torch

a = torch.arange(5, dtype=torch.float)
mask = torch.ones(5, dtype=torch.bool)
mask[2] = 0
mask_empty = torch.zeros(5, dtype=torch.bool)

a_masked = a[mask]
a_empty = a[mask_empty]
m = torch.mean(a_masked)
m_empty = torch.mean(a_empty)

print(m)
print(m_empty)
```

current output:

```
tensor(2.)
tensor(nan)
```

required output:

```
tensor(2.)
tensor(0.)
```

---

I know I can do

```
m_empty = torch.zeros_like(m_empty) if torch.isnan(m_empty) else m_empty
```

but this seems like the wrong way to go, as it forces more cpu-gpu communication that I would like to avoid if possible.
Also, this makes the code less clean than if something like
`m_empty = torch.mean(a_empty, default=0)` were available.

---

Is there a clean, Pythonic way of achieving default values for empty slices of `torch.mean` [or other standard functions]?

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the best way and is not as clean as what you are looking for however, one way to achieve this is to check the length of the Tensor prior to calculating the mean,

```
import torch

a = torch.arange(5, dtype=torch.float)
mask = torch.ones(5, dtype=torch.bool)
mask[2] = 0
mask_empty = torch.zeros(5, dtype=torch.bool)
a_masked = a[mask]
a_empty = a[mask_empty]
m = torch.mean(a_masked) if len(a_masked) > 0 else torch.tensor(0.)
m_empty = torch.mean(a_empty) if len(a_empty) > 0 else torch.tensor(0.)

print(m)
print(m_empty)
```

Output,

```
tensor(2.)
tensor(0.)
```